# WHM: domain isn't directing to account, but is going to server IP

Tags: dns, cpanel, whm

Hoping someone might be able to help me here.  Normally when we set up for a client, we own and have control over the domain, with our own private WHM server.  In this case, the client already registered the domain using their tech dept.  Their techs, simply directed it to the IP address of our servers, so the domains are going to the awful splash page WHM provides, but it doesn't seem to be going to the account that I set up for it in the WHM.... What am I missing? I can log in with the domain and login settings I set up for the account under PHP... but the domain itself in a browser, isn't working...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out, and am answering for those in the same issue.  Flush your DNS ( cmd /ipconfig flushdns), and clear your cache, or try on another computer.